# ASPX scraping with Mechanize: Can't retrieve form?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape [an .aspx web page](http://corporate.marksandspencer.com/aboutus/where/international_stores) using Python Mechanize. But I keep getting a funny `ParseError: unexpected '[' char in declaration` error, even when I manually remove the DTD.

Here is my code in full:

```
url = 'http://corporate.marksandspencer.com/aboutus/where/international_stores'
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(url)
browser.select_form(nr=0)
```

It fails with `ParseError: unexpected '[' char in declaration` on the final line. Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong?

Comment: Hm, you might want to clean up the code in this post- ie, `url` vs `INTERNATIONAL_URL`...

Comment: why you dont use lxml parsing?

Comment: I need to submit the `<select>` element to get the store locations.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Ruby mechanize handles it fine if you don't mind switching.

Answer (score 6):

I also had a similar kind of issue. I added the following line at the start and it worked for me.

```
self.browser = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
```